# I need a document preparation tool to document my jersey rest webservices

Tags: java, api, documentation, jersey

I want to document my jersey web services what my thought is i want to document the input data which we are passing to the service and also the parameters which we are passing to the service, so that the document readers can understand about the services in a better way.

For example

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/getuserbyid/{uid}")
    public Response getuserbyid(@PathParam("uid") int id)
```

Is our code means the document should have to information about the Path Params and input body if present for other services.

I don't have any idea how to implement this

Comment: Take a look at [Swagger](https://helloreverb.com/developers/swagger).

Comment: [This](http://swagger.io/) link is best.

Comment: Thanks , swagger works really well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger is one of the best documenting tool for documenting the Rest full web services. [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714029/howto-automate-documentation-of-a-rest-api-jersey-implementation?rq=1)