# Is there a tool that can parse Jersey-annotated classes and produce a REST-only documentation?

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm basically looking for a simple tool, optimally, a Maven plugin which can scan the sources (perhaps as an annotation processor, or something) and generate documentation based on the various Jersey-annotated methods.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714029/howto-automate-documentation-of-a-rest-api-jersey-implementation) contains the answer to your question.

Comment: To the downvoter, not cool, man. Not cool! I know there are tools out there. I'm looking for one that has a Maven plugin and is specifically aimed at Jersey, if possible. When you down-vote, put a comment, otherwise a -2 makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think [JAX-RS Analyzer](https://github.com/sdaschner/jaxrs-analyzer) could be what you are looking for. You can run it directly from the jar file or via a Maven plugin.

> It gathers the information about the JAX-RS resource classes by
>   bytecode analysis (not just by reflection). This gains more
>   information in several situations. You don’t need additional
>   annotations on your JAX-RS resource methods. Using the JSR 339
>   standard is sufficient.